# How To Create Dynamic more than one uiview with Marquee Effect in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, effect, marquee

I need to create more than one UIView with MARQUEE effect like HTML `<marquee>` tag.

I first need to create UIView dynamically.

After add a MARQUEE effect for dynamically created UIView.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Two things: your question isn't clear, and what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to create uiview dynamically and move the uiview once horizontal like html marquee tag without repeation dynamic uiview...!

Comment: You mean you're creating more than one view? What's going to be in the views?

Comment: Yes,i am trying like games click to dynamic uiview to hide at the point and regenerate dynamic uiview with horizontal moving..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean a view that can display a collection of strings that are wider than the view's width which it displays by slowly scrolling them from right to left?  You'd need to build it.  I did once, by subclassing UIScrollView like this:

```
// CrawlView.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CrawlView : UIScrollView

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSTimeInterval period;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *messages;

- (void)go;

@end


// CrawlView.m

#import "CrawlView.h"

// distance between neighboring strings.  could make this a public property
#define kPADDING 16.0

@interface CrawlView ()

@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat messagesWidth;

@end

@implementation CrawlView

@synthesize period=_period;
@synthesize messages=_messages;
@synthesize messagesWidth=_messagesWidth;

- (void)buildSubviews {

    for (UIView *subview in [self subviews]) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel self]]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    CGFloat xPos = kPADDING;

    for (NSString *message in self.messages) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        label.text = message;
        CGSize size = [message sizeWithFont:label.font];
        CGFloat width = size.width + kPADDING;
        label.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 0.0, width, self.frame.size.height);
        [self addSubview:label];
        xPos += width;
    }
    self.messagesWidth = xPos;
    self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(xPos, self.frame.size.height);
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(-self.frame.size.width, 0.0);
}

- (void)setMessages:(NSMutableArray *)messages {

    if (_messages != messages) {
        _messages = messages;
        [self buildSubviews];
    }
}

- (void)go {

    if (!self.period) self.period = self.messagesWidth / 100;
    // so it always takes about the same (fudged, but reasonable) amount of time to scroll the whole array

    [UIView animateWithDuration:self.period
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear |UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                     animations:^{
                         self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.messagesWidth, 0.0);
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}


@end
```

Comment: How to use this function...!, and it shows Error in this line-@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *messages; the error message is unkown property strong

Comment: It's targeted to iOS SDK 5.1 (using ARC).  Can you build for OS5?  If not, you can see how it works by changing that strong to "retain", but don't ship it that way.  It will leak memory unless you do additional work.

Comment: oh, so you'll have to monkey a bit with that code to make sure it releases memory properly.  but it will probably work for you in demo mode by changing to "retain" instead of strong.  use it like this:

Comment: place it on a view via IB or the way you would add a scroll view... 1) CrawlView *cv = [[CrawlView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,320,30)]; 2) [self.view addSubView:cv]; 3) cv.messages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hi", "there", @"dinesh", nil]; 4) [cv go];  5) [cv release]; // pre-arc