# Accessor method is not called

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to build a dynamic marquee using the solution provided in this article:

[How To Create Dynamic more than one uiview with Marquee Effect in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919455/how-to-create-dynamic-more-than-one-uiview-with-marquee-effect-in-iphone)

The problem ins that method accessor. Thats how I implemented in my view controller:

gridViewController.h

```
#import "CrawlView.h" 

CrawlView *marquee;

@property (strong, nonatomic) CrawlView *marquee;

gridViewController.m

@synthesize marquee;

....

[marquee setMessages:self.noticiasArray];

[marquee go];
```

I put a break point in the accessor method, but it's never called:

```
- (void)setMessages:(NSMutableArray *)messages {

    if (_messages != messages) {
        _messages = messages;
        [self buildSubviews];
    }
}
```

So the marquee is not shown.

I will appreciate your help on this.

thnaks

Comment: did you define the property Messages in your crawl class?

Comment: @synthesize messages=_messages;

yes, they are

Comment: can you post a little more of your code, or is it same as in the link you posted above?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it to @dynamic

```
 @dynamic marquee;
```

instead of @synthesize marquee; in order to use your custom setter

Comment: I have changed it to dynamic, but it doesn't work, it is not accessing the custom method.

Answer (score 1):

Try self.marquee to call the accessor method.

Comment: It gave me this error: [gridViewController marquee]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8638170
This is very strange